# How do I write a file with Ruby within a Docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

I am trying to write a new file using Ruby dockerized. I can read the file after writing it but just inside the container. I tried to create a volume and save the file in it but I am doing something wrong because the data folder is always empty.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir /data
VOLUME data data
COPY hello.rb .
ENTRYPOINT ["ruby", "hello.rb"]
```

And here is hello.rb

```
File.open("./data/out.txt", "a+") do |line|
  puts "hola"
  line.puts "\r" + "write your stuff here"
end
File.open("./data/out.txt").each do |line|
  puts "aloha"
  puts line
end

File.write("./data/log.txt", "data...", mode: "a")
File.open("./data/log.txt").each do |line|
  puts "aloha"
  puts line
end
```

After running:

```
$ docker build -t file-writer .
$ docker run -it file-writer
```

The output in the console is:

```
hola

aloha

write your stuff here

aloha

data...
```

But the "local" data folder stills empty.

Comment: I've removed the `ruby` tag because your question doesn't *really* have anything to do with this. The question is all about `docker`, so I've left it tagged as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to setup your `mount` during run stage

remove `VOLUME data data` from your `Dockerfile` and run the container :

```
docker run -it -v /full/path/to/data:/data file-writer
```

Comment: Thanks, it sounds promising but  I get this error: `docker: Error response from daemon: create ./data: "./data" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.`

Comment: @Ibrah, you need to provide the full, absolute path to the directories you would like to map with `--volume`. Relative paths like `./data` won't work. To make relative paths absolute quickly on Unix systems, you can use `pwd`: `--volume $(pwd)/data:/data`.